# How to create switch buttons on react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, react-native

I try to use this https://github.com/ArnaudRinquin/react-native-radio-buttons
On Iphone it looks good, but on android it looks like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARW10.png)

Comment: looks like a border-radius problem in the css

Comment: Can you help me to fix it? I think need to write overflow:hidden, but it's not available on react-native:/

Comment: not without code - but from here it looks like a css issue.

Comment: If the code is exactly the same - then its a compatibility issue somewhere down the line.  Try doing a simpler button from scratch and see what you find - or get rid of any extra stylesheets/js and see if you can't isolate that part that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If you can set the style props of the buttons container, you need to set the property `overflow` in your js `StyleSheet` like that:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   containerStyle: {
     ...,
     overflow: 'hidden',
   },
});
```